# Error: declaration does not declare anything

Tags: c++, linux, g++

This is a very amateur question with what I'm sure is going to be a very simple answer, but I cannot seem to figure out the problem. I have a header file with a corresponding .cpp file, but for some reason whenever I try to compile with g++, I keep getting the error:

> declaration does not declare anything

I'm pretty sure the problem is that I'm not initializing the (only) variable in the file, but I'm not sure what to initialize it to. If anyone can help, I would greatly appreciate it! Here are my files:

SymbolTableDictionary.h

```
#ifndef SymbolTable
#define SymbolTable
#include <new>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#pragma once

struct Symbol
{
    std::string Name;
    int Address;

    Symbol::Symbol()
    { }

    Symbol::Symbol(const string name, int address)
    {
        std::string sym(name);
        this->Name = sym;
        this->Address = address;
    }
};

extern map<std::string, Symbol> SymbolTable;

#endif
```

SymbolTableDictionary.cpp

```
#include <new>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <map>

#include "SymbolTableDictionary.h"

using namespace std;

map<std::string, Symbol> SymbolTable;
```

Compilation errors:

```
In file included from SymbolTableDictionary.cpp:8:0:
SymbolTableDictionary.h:18:5: error: extra qualification ‘Symbol::’ on member ‘Symbol’ [-fpermissive]
SymbolTableDictionary.h:21:5: error: extra qualification ‘Symbol::’ on member ‘Symbol’ [-fpermissive]
SymbolTableDictionary.h:29:8: error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
SymbolTableDictionary.cpp:12:1: error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: You should avoid `<cstdlib>` and `<cstdio>` in most C++ programs, let alone `<stdlib.h>` and `<stdio.h>`.  Also, it is generally considered ill-advised to use `using namespace std;`, and it is considered ill-mannered to add it to a header.  It would help if you identified the line where the compiler reports the problem.

Comment: I suggest using header guards with some variation on the theme of `#ifndef SYMBOLTABLEDICTIONARY_H_INCLUDED` (all caps, based on the name of the file, name unlikely to be used for other purposes).  Another reasonable suggestion is to use a name based on the MD5 hash of the contents of some version of the file: `#ifndef H_779f06b8e4323b7991ddfd9078d79923` perhaps.

Comment: The fact that the header guard and variable name were the same was what caused the problem. Can't believe I did not see that before. Thanks for everyone's help! Much appreciated!

Comment: For reference, inside the `Symbol` struct, you don't need to call your constructor `Symbol::Symbol()`, etc. The errors about the extra `Symbol::` essentially tell you you're over-qualifying the name.  Just call them `Symbol()` etc instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Doing that is some weird habit of mine. Are there any problems that can occur from doing that?

Comment: A C++ compiler could refuse to compile your code; but apart from little things like that, ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is this code:

```
// header
#ifndef SymbolTable
#define SymbolTable

// implementation
map<std::string, Symbol> SymbolTable;
```

You #define `SymbolTable` to empty. Therefore the advise to

1. Always use ALL_UPPERCASE_NAMES for macros (also for include guards)
2. Use macro names only for macros.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I overlooked that! That did it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

```
#infndef SymbolTable
#define SymbolTable
..
#endif
```

You could just use

```
#pragma once
```

As far as I know, they do the same thing. But you don't have to deal with the name being the same as something else.

Comment: @VasilyBiryukov Yes it does... What version are you running? How are you compiling? I use `#prgama once` for all my code, haven't had any issues with it using g++

Comment: You are right, g++ [supports](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.0/cpp/Alternatives-to-Wrapper-_0023ifndef.html) `#prama once`. I've missed that. +1 to you.

Answer (score 3):

The name of your map `SymbolTable` is the same as macro used in include guard

```
#ifndef SymbolTable
#define SymbolTable
```

Because this macro is empty your declaration looks like this

```
map<std::string, Symbol> ; //note: no name
```

The solution is to use more ugly macro name for include guard, for example:

```
#ifndef SYMBOL_TABLE_H
#define SYMBOL_TABLE_H
```