# conversion from C to C++ - cannot compile

Tags: c++

Hi I have a code at http://pastebin.com/CjCd5APn.
Problem is that during compilation I get tons of errors like:

```
Error: Identifier "lastButton" is undefined in "ft800.cpp", Line: 406, Col: 6  
Error: "this" may only be used inside a nonstatic member function in "ft800.cpp", Line: 740, Col: 6  
Warning: Nonstandard qualified name in global scope declaration in "ft800.cpp", Line: 445, Col: 12
```

Do you have an idea why is it happening? Did I omit something?

Comment: The error messages are enough clear. The compiler issues them personally for you.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow i follow some of your your answers and it seems that you are a great C++ programmer.  Can you please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40743948/the-c-equivalent-of-cs-format-string and give an answer, because I get not a single answer yet. Thank you.

Comment: but lastButton is defined, and functions are not static... and I don't even know what third means.

Comment: You omitted posting the *text* of your code in your question.

Comment: I can't post it because it is too big - that's why I used pastebin. And if I posted it without some declarations u would probably start asking about them before the main problem.

Comment: @yanoyesterday, trying hijack WHAT? What do you mean?

Answer (score -1):

The problem was with define in the top. I couldn't find it but now it is solved.

define directive should always be written so it can never be used by accident in code. The best way to do this is to use uppercase letters as it is reserved for preprocessor language.

[Error: declaration does not declare anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985542/error-declaration-does-not-declare-anything)

Comment: This is a useless answer if you don't explain how you fixed it.

Comment: You've been a member of SO for 6 years, surely you know what a good question and answer look like.